# android_tutorial_hokuyo dependency not satisfied

Tags: android-core, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

My android_core build fails due to a dependency problem, and I tired everything that I thought might help but unfortunately didn't solve my problem, here is the output of my `./gradlew debug`:

```
:android_tutorial_hokuyo:deployLibs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':android_tutorial_hokuyo:compile'.
> Could not find group:ros.google, module:hokuyo, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      ros.android_core:android_tutorial_hokuyo:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I appreciate any help that might solve the problem.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34386/android_tutorial_hokuyo-dependency-not-satisfied/) by [Sam_h](https://answers.ros.org/users/1955/sam_h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2012-05-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should build google first.
roscd google
./gradlew install

This should fix it.
And then you will probably get the ant errors again but you know what to do with them.

---

Originally posted by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) with karma: 155 on 2012-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3